# MSK_AWS cluster Issue with Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create MSK_AWS cluster with terraform. With new released version of terraform, AWS_MSK cluster is not getting created.

Here is the code used below

```
resource "aws_msk_cluster" "msk_cluster" {
    cluster_name = "Testing_Cluster"
    kafka_version = "2.1.0"
    number_of_broker_nodes = 3
    broker_node_group_info {
    instance_type = "kafka.m5.large"
    client_subnets = [
    "${aws_subnet.subnet_a.id}",
    "${aws_subnet.subnet_b.id}",
    "${aws_subnet.subnet_c.id}",
    ]
    ebs_volume_size = 5
    security_groups = [ "${aws_security_group.MSK_Sg.id}" ]
    }
    tags = {
    Name = "Cluster_MSK"
    }
    }
```

But I am getting the error

> BadRequestException: The parameter value contains one or more
>   characters that are not valid.status code: 400, request id:
>   e2589e6a-8161-11e9-8f31-6f8877605e30.

Answer (score 3):

MSK doesn't support underscores in the `aws_msk_cluster.cluster_name` and `aws_msk_configuration.name` parameters. 
In your case simply use `cluster_name = "Testing-Cluster"`.

Comment: ah! the pesky underscores!